# Docker Build using Buildkit any way to log which file burst the cache?

Tags: docker, caching

In gradle, tests are run as part of the build, so I use a test report target from "scratch" to copy the test results from the "build" target. For some reason on some of my builds the cache is burst when I do this and it re-runs the entire build again! I know it's probably something being written outside of .dockerignore, but I have no idea what. Is there any way to log which file(s) burst the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. What I ended up doing was swapping my `.gitignore` for my `.dockerignore` and reproducing the Dockerfile run in a git context. This let me identify what changed at each step using `git status`